# GraphQL: Nested queries vs root queries

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm using Apollo GraphQL on my server, and I'm trying to design my GraphQL API. One question I have is whether or not I should prefer nested queries over root queries.

Let's examine both in this example where the current user, `me`, has many `invitations`.

**Root queries**

```
me {
    id
    name
}

invitations {
    id
    message
}
```

The resolver for `invitations` returns invitations for the current user.

**Nested query**

```
me {
    id
    name
    invitations {
        id
        message
    }
}
```

These should achieve the same result, except in the latter approach invitations are nested inside the user object `me`. My concern is whether this will work smoothly with Apollo Client and keep the cache consistent.

What is the recommended way to design GraphQL queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it really depends on the case. Personally, I treat nested properties as a *context*: if the API consumer wants to fetch *mine notifications*, then it's `me  { notifications { ... } }`, not `notifications { ... }`. If it makes sense to have a top-level key, for example, there's a concept of *global* notifications (not user-dependent), then go for it. If every user has own notifications (which I assume is true), then `me` of type `User` should have it, as every `User` does. Such generalization encourages reusable thinking: an admin panel, where `user(id: ...) { ... }` is being used instead of `me { ... }`, can use the same UI code *for free*.

As a rule of thumb, it's better to think about consuming that API, not providing it.

Answer (score 3):

One of the GraphQL selling point is to allow client to have very much flexibility to define the shape of the data they want to query in a minimised number of requests. They also encourage developers to "[Think in Graphs](https://graphql.github.io/learn/thinking-in-graphs/)" when designing the schema.

So, I would go for nested query which looks more like a graph. Furthermore, it is much more flexible. If user want to get their user profile data with their invitations, they can get them in a single request only. If they only want to get the profile data, they just ignore the invitation part in the query and server will not waste any resources to get the invitation data due to the design nature of the GraphQL.